# Google Glass Menu Options (Button Navigation)

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I have 3 simple menu options.

Currently Tapping or calling Application Name Say"Hello World" takes them to Application home.
For menu options to show up, user is got to tap again
To switch menu, user will have to swipe forward
To return to home, user will have to swipe back

I am sure, our friends in business will say make it simple. The user base will not always like voice because they may be in a noisy environment though I have one menu option with a text view where I expect voice input.

If I were to provide multiple buttons on Application home, Is there a way for users to navigate between buttons and allow them to tap.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu buttons are pretty inconsistent with how Glassware typically operates. Menu options are each presented on a card, since they're easier to read and control by a user. The swipe and select method is probably *easier* than buttons on Glass.

More commonly, however, would be to use a different voice command to trigger each operation instead of using a menu. Typically with Glass, you don't think about what app you're running - you think about what command you want to issue to Glass.

If you really feel you need buttons, and that voice commands are inappropriate, you may wish to reconsider the interface completely. It may just not be a good design fit for Glass.

Comment: I knew "Menu option are each presented on a card" and thats exactly how it is. But I wanted to make sure, there are no additional options that I missed. I want to give one more try before marking your answer correct. Will ListView work along with using Gesturedetector and identifying TAP, SWIPE_RIGHT and SWIPE_LEFT. One thing to note is, getting used to glass swipes takes a while, if it is not motivated user. So aiming for simplicity in POC for acceptance

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use ListView. It sounds like you are trying to create the menu system manually. What you do is add each menu item you want in the Menu.xml and then open it on a tap using the GestureDetector and they will be able to swipe between each menu item you have defined. Just listen for the id of the item to decide what to do when it is tapped. Also a note is if you are going to have different menu items for different parts in the same activity make sure to override onPrepareOptionsMenu.

Here is an example of the menu system here if it helps: https://github.com/w9jds/GlassMenuExample

Comment: Nice example, was very easy to reproduce the menu using your code. Thanks!